# High fan speed with no reason

Tags: linux, fan, thinkpad

For a few weeks, the fans of my Lenovo B590 laptop, running on Xubuntu 14, turn to high speed a few minutes after it is turned on. The fans won't speed down until I turn the computer off.

This is quite strange, since

**This didn't happen before**

**The temperatures are quite low** (are they ?)

```
$sensors
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +36.0°C  (crit = +88.0°C)
temp2:        +30.0°C  (crit = +126.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +37.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 0:         +34.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:         +31.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM

pkg-temp-0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +37.0°C 

$sudo hddtemp /dev/sda
/dev/sda: ST500LT012-9WS142: 33°C
```

**The computer is under low load:**

```
top - 08:30:15 up 16 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.28, 0.23, 0.23
Tasks: 197 total,   1 running, 196 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3607944 total,  1973956 used,  1633988 free,    99660 buffers
KiB Swap:  3744764 total,        0 used,  3744764 free.   789936 cached Mem
```

**The BIOS is up to date** (and there are no fan settings in it)

**The fan is clean and dust-free**

Why would the BIOS turn the fans to high speed where there seem to be no reason for that ?

It seems that we cannot control the fan manually with this model, so I guess the only solution is to understand why this happens.

Comment: linux ACPI power management implementations are hit and miss with many laptop bioses. consider yourself lucky that it has your fans on high, rather than low. I had a laptop I couldn't do anything serious with becuase ubuntu couldn't tell the HP bios to spin them up when needed, so they never ran above low, even at a coretemp above 80C. HP of course would not relase a bios that had powermanagement configuration available.

Comment: I have a laptop which does the same: I can't remember whether hibernating cured it, but my Lenovo has not exhibited the problem. Apart from the hardware, the main differences are that the Lenovo has UEFI and 64-bit Ubuntu. Both are running 12.10.

Comment: @AFH What do you mean by `whether hibernating cured it` ?

Comment: It was configured to hibernate when the lid was closed, which stopped the fan: I can't recall if the fan came back to full speed when I resumed. I don't often use it now, so I have had no recent incidents. If your Lenovo is configured to hibernate, it's worth checking if this will reset it: it's a lot quicker than rebooting.

Comment: @Klaus: What do you mean by "This didn't happen before". Before _what_? OS upgrade? Switch from Windows to Linux? BIOS update?

Comment: Try a live CD - if this still happens then my guess is that a sensor has gone bad.

Comment: @mpy It seems to have appeared out of nowhere. I tried a clean install, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @harrymc But doesn't `sensors` indicate that the sensors measure rather low temperatures ?

Comment: Sensors support is sometimes very sketchy, so such indications are not conclusive.

Comment: Check the BIOS to see if it has settings for allowing dynamic fan speed.  I have seen some systems that had fan settings in the BIOS that either allowed direct control from the BIOS or set what could control the fans.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible the fan is just running at the default speed for the power its getting if the bios has no setting for fan speed control? software issue?

seems their are many other people with your same issue

please refer [here](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/Lenovo-B590-noise-level-issue/td-p/1231603)

the issue is still yet to be resolved with out having my hands on an B590 its hard for me to help you further. I think it most likely is a driver or bios issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your temperatures seem fine, but what i noticed is that the fan speed reported is 0 RPM .

That kind of a bad sign.
either the fan probe dies [by overheat/usage/bad connection] , or its a software issue.

If the reports you posted are from BIOS then i would suggest taking a screwdriver to it and seeing whats up [only if you have done this sort of thing before - otherwise seek advise!]

Otherwise, it should be solved chipset drivers or such.

Does this happen wheather you boot into ubuntu or not? Does the fan go to full speed before ubuntu?
I would also try booting a live CD ad seeing what happens.

good luck , report back!

Answer (score 0):

i would say it is software issue, i have the same issue, all of the sudden the fan will run fast, and the case is getting hot, i check temp it registering 80 deg C, usually it does not exceed over 60 deg, I immediately open terminal and type in reboot, after that will run normal again.